# What Is the Difference Between a Tag and an Element?

Tags: xml, terminology

In some texts about XML, the terms *tag* and *element* seem to be used interchangeably. Do they mean the same thing, or are do these terms represent different things?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Tags mark the start and end of an element.

- `<foo>` — start tag
- `</foo>` — end tag
- `<foo></foo>` — element

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-logical-struct):

> Each XML document contains one or more elements, the boundaries of which are either delimited by start-tags and end-tags, or, for empty elements, by an empty-element tag.

---

See also section 5 of [NOT the comp.text.sgml FAQ](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/faq-not.txt)

Comment: Also note that the stuff between the start tag `<foo>` and the end tag `</foo>` is called the "element content". It could be empty (no space, no carriage return, no line feed, no tab, nothing at all).

Comment: Should you say "the element foo", "the element FOO", "the element <foo>" or "the element "<foo></foo>"?

Comment: @Maggyero I would say the lesser the better. So I would choose `"the element foo"`.

Comment: @Maggyero, I'd say "the foo element". Thinking about how you talk about HTML, you'd talk about a div element, not an element div.

Answer (score 3):

HTML elements are defined by a starting tag, may contain some content and a closing tag whereas Tags are the starting and ending parts of an HTML element.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<address category = "residence">
    <name>name content</name>
    <company>company content</company>
    <phone>(011) 123-4567</phone>
</address>
```

Here `<address>` is an element which has attribute `category`

Start and end `tags` of an `element` must be identical.