# to make distinct values in two attributes of an xml tag by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im trying to catch distinct values of two differents tag.
The tags "@mandante" and "@visitante" in //jogo, represents country, so i want to generate a list with different countries values.

what i have

```
<xsl:key name="contry" match="//jogo/@mandante | //jogo/@visitante" use="text()"/>
...
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="(//jogo/@mandante | //jogo/@visitante)[generate-id()= generate-id(key('contry',text()))]">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
   </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

xml file exemple

```
<grupo nome="A">
    <jogo data="1982-06-14T17:15:00+03:00" mandante="Itália" visitante="Polónia">
    </jogo>
    <jogo data="1982-06-15T17:15:00+03:00" mandante="Peru" visitante="Camarões">
    </jogo>
    <jogo data="1982-06-18T17:15:00+03:00" mandante="Itália" visitante="Peru">
        <eventos>
            <evento tipo="gol" time="mandante">
                <jogador>Conti</jogador>
                <minuto>18</minuto>
            </evento>
            <evento tipo="gol" time="visitante">
                <jogador>Díaz</jogador>
                <minuto>83</minuto>
            </evento>
        </eventos>
    </jogo>
</grupo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@mandante` and `@visitante` are not *tags*. They are ***attributes*** - and attributes do not have child text nodes. This is why your expression `text()` selects nothing, both in the `key` definition and in the `key()` call.

Note also that using `//` in a match pattern does not do anything.

Try it this way instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:key name="country" match="jogo/@mandante | jogo/@visitante" use="."/>
...
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="(//jogo/@mandante | //jogo/@visitante)[generate-id()= generate-id(key('country', .))]">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
   </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do not know why I was treating attribute as tag, thanks! it helped a lot!

Comment: Actually, you were trying to treat it as an ***element***. A ***tag*** means something else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027770/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tag-and-an-element